# Laravel ERROR: Creating default object from empty value in Excel Import

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

While trying to update database using Excel:

```
public function collection(Collection $rows)
{            
    foreach ($rows as $row) 
    {
        $this->gradelevel = $row['grade_level_code'];
            $employeegrade = HrEmployee::where('company_id',auth()->user()->company_id)->where('employee_code', $row['staff_id'])->where('email', $row['official_email']) ->first();
            $employeegrade->grade_level_id = $this->getGradeLevel();
            $employeegrade->save();           
    }
}

public function getGradeLevel(){
    if(!empty($this->gradelevel) || !$this->gradelevel){

        return HrGradeLevel::where('grade_level_code',$this->gradelevel)->where('company_id',Auth::user()->company_id)->pluck('id')->first();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> production.ERROR: Creating default object from empty value

and it points to this line:

> $employeegrade->grade_level_id = $this->getGradeLevel();

How do I get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

most probably this will return null

```
  $employeegrade = HrEmployee::where('company_id',auth()->user()->company_id)->where('employee_code', $row['staff_id'])->where('email', $row['official_email']) ->first();
```

You can also use firstOrNew() if not exist then will create new object of HrEmployee

```
$employeegrade = HrEmployee::firstOrNew(array("column"=>value, "column2"=>value));
```

if you want update the existing record only use as

```
$employeegrade = HrEmployee::where('company_id',auth()->user()->company_id)->where('employee_code', $row['staff_id'])->where('email', $row['official_email']) ->first()

if(!$employeegrade){
    //log error employee nit found
}else
{
    //update record
}
```

Comment: The error changed to production.ERROR: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::firstOrNew(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\Imports\EmployeeGradeLevelsImport.php on line 49 and at least 1 expected. This is line 49:  $employeegrade = HrEmployee::where('company_id',auth()->user()->company_id)->where('employee_code', $row['staff_id'])->where('email', $row['official_email']) ->firstOrNew();.  It suppose to list all the failures on a table using flash.

Comment: @mikefolu please check updated answer, columns=>values are same attributes you use in where condition

Comment: Are the where clause not going to be there again?

Comment: $employeegrade = HrEmployee::firstOrNew(array("company_id"=>auth()->user()->company_id, "employee_code"=>$row['staff_id'], "email"=>$row['official_email']));

Comment: make sure indexes used in $row,  should exist

Comment: I'm sorry. How do you mean by "make sure indexes used in $row"

Comment: i mean staff_id and official_email indexes be in row array

Comment: try print_r($row) inside foreach.. and check it should be array like
array('staff_id'=>'',.....) with all other indexes you are using

Comment: I got something like Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [staff_id] => 11112 [first_name] => DENNISI [last_name] => PAUL [official_email] => adennis@email.com [grade_level_code] => DD2 ) )
true

Comment: Yes, but I got this error:  Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-11110' for key. This is for employee_code (staff_id). When there's failure, I expect it to do othere and skip failure. The show all the failed rows. But I got error-500 and  Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-11110' for key

Comment: please check updated answer, with query you are not getting record. if you there is record in database and still not getting, check your query and values are they correct with database record